# How to select button appearing in a new pop-up window in capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html style="">
<head>
<body class="hasMotif lookupTab LookupSearchFrame brandNoBgrImg" onfocus="if(this.bodyOnFocus)bodyOnFocus();" onload="if(this.bodyOnLoad)bodyOnLoad();" onbeforeunload="if(this.bodyOnBeforeUnload){var s=bodyOnBeforeUnload();if(s)return s;}" onunload="if(this.bodyOnUnload)bodyOnUnload();">
<form id="theForm" target="resultsFrame" onsubmit="if (window.ffInAlert) { return false; }" name="theForm" method="GET" action="/_ui/common/data/LookupResultsFrame">
<input id="lkfm" type="hidden" value="editPage" name="lkfm">
<input id="lknm" type="hidden" value="Account" name="lknm">
<input id="lktp" type="hidden" value="001" name="lktp">
<div class="lookup">
<div class="bPageTitle">
<div class="pBody">
<label class="assistiveText" for="lksrch">Search</label>
<input id="lksrch" type="text" value="" size="20" placeholder="Search..." name="lksrch" maxlength="80">

###
<input class="btn" type="submit" title="Go!" name="go" value=" Go! ">

###
<input class="btn" type="button" title="New" onclick="javascript:top.resultsFrame.location='LookupResultsFrame?lktp=001&lkfm=editPage&lknm=Account&lksrch=&lkenhmd=SEARCH_NAME&lknew=1&igdp=0'" name="new" value=" New ">
<div class="bDescription">You can use "*" as a wildcard next to other characters to improve your search results.</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

This above is the code for content of pop-up window and i have to select the Go button.

My code is as follows:

```
  #Get the main window handle
  main = page.driver.browser.window_handles.first
  #Get the popup window handle
  popup = page.driver.browser.window_handles.last

  #Then switch control between the windows
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(popup)

  page.driver.browser.switch_to.frame("searchFrame")


  # within(".pBody") do
    # find("go").click
  # end

  #find("#theForm").first("div").all("div")[2].all("input")[2].click

  #find(:xpath, "//*[@id='theForm']/div/div[2]/input[2]").click
```

I've tried within method and find method, using xpath to click the Go button but the error i get is "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". Help me out, please?

Comment: are you sure capybara is even running javascript? See the capybara readme's [note on drivers](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers). Or maybe try phantomjs.

Comment: I am using selenium webdriver for running javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is to to stop using driver specific methods and use the Capybara API provided for working with windows.  Assuming you are in the current session you can do

```
popup = window_opened_by do
  click_link 'open new window' # whatever action opens the popup window
end

within_window(popup) do
  click_button('Go!')
end
```

Note - this isn't handling any 'searchFrame' frame that you attempt to switch to, but that frame isn't shown in the HTML either, so it's not exactly clear whats going on there - if the frame is in the popup window then you would use `#within_frame' provided by Capybara to switch to the frame inside the within_window block like

```
within_window(popup) do
  within_frame('searchFrame') do
    click_button('Go!')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank You for the solution. But when I try this i get an error as "(Capybara::ElementNotFound)".

Comment: @BharatMohite you get that error where? Is there actually a frame that you didn't show in your question (but show trying to change to)?

Comment: @BharatMohite I've added whats needed if there is actually a frame in the popup (your question isn't clear about that).   Also, when using Capybara you should refrain from using #first and #all if possible, especially on dynamic pages since they dont have waiting behavior by default and the elements returned by them are not reloadable by chained finders as the page changes - which lead to flaky tests and stale element references

Comment: I click a search link and a pop-up window opens which has two frames 'search' & 'result'. The search frame has 'form' with id and name in which is defined the Go button.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The solution you provided worked. Also, i'll keep in mind your suggestions about not using #first & #all.